# I am getting this alert in Android developer console

Tags: android

**Security alert**

Your app is using an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

**Vulnerable classes:**

```
com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity$AuthenticatorTask$1
com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGService$CancelTransactionThread$1
com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGService$StatusQueryThread$1
```

I checked gradle I am not able to see any any paytm dependency.

Comment: check your dependency from file-project structure

Comment: Have you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I found pgsdk.jar  library, I removed it for now as I am not using paytm payment gateway anymore, this should fix problem. Will get to know when I deploy next version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the jar file. They have released new jar v1.0.1
[PGSDK](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Android_App_Kit/blob/master/android%20SDK/PGSDK_v1.0.1.jar)

Comment: as new jar is removed by the paytm Is anyone have jar v1.0.1 PGSDK ?